# Cálculo de horas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Preciso implementar um relatório de horas trabalhadas dentro de um período.

A minha dificuldade é a seguinte: os registros de cada dia estão em linhas diferentes e por conta disso, estou com dificuldade de bater a entrada e saída dos dias certos e ainda tenho que subtrair o horário de almoço desse total.

E ainda tem um outro problema: e se no dia a pessoa só fez a entrada e o almoço? Eu teria que calcular esse período trabalhado.

Minha tabela é mais ou menos assim:

```
+------------------+-------------------+
|     horario      |       acao        |
+------------------+-------------------+
| 2018/09/14 08:00 | Entrada           |
| 2018/09/14 12:00 | Almoço            |
| 2018/09/14 13:00 | Volta almoço      |
| 2018/09/14 17:00 | Fim de expediente |
| 2018/09/15 08:00 | Entrada           |
| 2018/09/15 12:00 | Almoço            |
| 2018/09/15 13:00 | Volta almoço      |
| 2018/09/15 17:00 | Fim de expediente |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

Fiz um select que chegou próximo, mas não consegui subtrair o período de almoço:

```
Select id_colaborador, timediff(Max (horario) ,min(horario)) from tabela group by day(horario) , id_colaborador
```

Eu queria um relatório que viesse o período de dias e as horas trabalhadas naquele dia, mais ou menos isso.

Alguém tem alguma ideia? Tratar pelo programa de alguma forma seria mais fácil? A ideia inicial minha é receber filtrar por período de data e colaborador.

Comment: Eu faria uma FUNCTION pois permite tratar exceções etc. Quais as regras de negócio para "não marcação" ? Outra coisa a pensar é o "vigia da noite" que entra às 20h e sai às 6h do dia seguinte ...

Answer (score 1):

Acho que uma abordagem melhor é registrar apenas entradas e saídas, por vários motivos:

- Alguns não saem para almoçar.
- Alguns podem acabar tendo que sair mais de uma vez no meio do dia por algum motivo qualquer.
- Alguns podem sair para o almoço e não voltar mais no dia por algum motivo.

Não vou considerar esses casos:

- Devido a algum problema, não houve registro de entrada embora houvesse um registro de saída ou vice-versa.
- Ocorrerem duas entradas consecutivamente sem uma saída no meio ou duas saídas consecutivamente sem uma entrada no meio.
- Registro de saída sem registro de entrada correspondente.

A minha solução deve funcionar mesmo para o caso do trabalhador que entra num dia e sai no dia seguinte, virando a meia-noite no trabalho. Sou uma prova viva que esse caso acontece, já tive problemas com horários registrados no RH por esse exato motivo. O tempo nesse caso é computado no dia que entrou.

Primeiro, vamos construir um banco de dados para testes:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    id_colaborador int NOT NULL,
    horario datetime NOT NULL,
    acao varchar(20)
) engine = InnoDB CHARSET = utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/14 08:00', 'Entrada');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/14 12:00', 'Almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/14 13:00', 'Volta almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/14 17:00', 'Fim de expediente');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/15 08:00', 'Entrada');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/15 12:00', 'Almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/15 13:00', 'Volta almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (1, '2018/09/15 17:00', 'Fim de expediente');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/14 08:30', 'Entrada');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/14 12:30', 'Almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/14 13:30', 'Volta almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/14 17:30', 'Fim de expediente');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/15 08:30', 'Entrada');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/15 12:30', 'Almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/15 13:30', 'Volta almoço');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (2, '2018/09/15 17:30', 'Fim de expediente');

-- Virou a meia-noite no trabalho!
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (3, '2018/09/14 17:00', 'Entrada');
INSERT INTO tabela VALUES (3, '2018/09/15 02:00', 'Almoço');
```

Agora, vamos selecionar os pares de entrada e saída:

```
SELECT
    entrada.id_colaborador,
    entrada.horario AS entrada,
    (
        SELECT MIN(s.horario)
        FROM tabela s
        WHERE s.acao IN ('Almoço', 'Fim de expediente')
        AND s.id_colaborador = entrada.id_colaborador
        AND s.horario > entrada.horario
    ) AS saida
FROM tabela entrada
WHERE entrada.acao IN ('Entrada', 'Volta almoço');
```

A saída deverá ser essa:

```
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id_colaborador | entrada              | saida                |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1              | 2018-09-14T08:00:00Z | 2018-09-14T12:00:00Z |
| 1              | 2018-09-14T13:00:00Z | 2018-09-14T17:00:00Z |
| 1              | 2018-09-15T08:00:00Z | 2018-09-15T12:00:00Z |
| 1              | 2018-09-15T13:00:00Z | 2018-09-15T17:00:00Z |
| 2              | 2018-09-14T08:30:00Z | 2018-09-14T12:30:00Z |
| 2              | 2018-09-14T13:30:00Z | 2018-09-14T17:30:00Z |
| 2              | 2018-09-15T08:30:00Z | 2018-09-15T12:30:00Z |
| 2              | 2018-09-15T13:30:00Z | 2018-09-15T17:30:00Z |
| 3              | 2018-09-14T17:00:00Z | 2018-09-15T02:00:00Z |
+----------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Feito isso, agora só temos que juntar os pares entrada-saída do dia:

```
SELECT
    x.id_colaborador AS id_colaborador,
    DAY(x.entrada) AS dia,
    SUM(timediff(x.entrada, x.saida)) AS periodo
FROM (
    SELECT
        entrada.id_colaborador AS id_colaborador,
        entrada.horario AS entrada,
        (
            SELECT MIN(s.horario)
            FROM tabela s
            WHERE s.acao IN ('Almoço', 'Fim de expediente')
            AND s.id_colaborador = entrada.id_colaborador
            AND s.horario > entrada.horario
        ) AS saida
    FROM tabela entrada
    WHERE entrada.acao IN ('Entrada', 'Volta almoço')
) x
GROUP BY x.id_colaborador, DAY(x.entrada);
```

A saída deverá ser essa:

```
+----------------+------------+---------+
| id_colaborador | dia        | periodo |
+----------------+------------+---------+
| 1              | 2018-09-14 | 80000   |
| 1              | 2018-09-15 | 80000   |
| 2              | 2018-09-14 | 80000   |
| 2              | 2018-09-15 | 80000   |
| 3              | 2018-09-14 | 90000   |
+----------------+------------+---------+
```

Esse valor retornado no período está no formato `HMMSS`, ou seja, os últimos dois dígitos são os segundos, os dois anteriores os minutos e o restante são as horas.